# best place to fetch data before rendering in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I would like to know where I should fetch my data in the react life cycle.
I tried to put my data in the `componentDidMount()`and `componenWillMount()`
but without succes...

```
componentWillMount(){
   
 // this fetch the data from back-end set a store state with the payload
        this.props.fetchUser(); 
        this.setState({userData:this.props.auth});
}

//fetchMethod
export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch =>{//using redux-thunk


    const res= await axios.get('/api/current_user')

    dispatch({type:FETCH_USER, payload:res.data}); 
    
    

};
```

in my render function I tried to use fetched userData by calling `this.state.userData`. but it's undefined. I also tried to get it by calling the correct store state, also without succcess. The thing I don't get is, according to my localstorage that store state is defined. Hope someone can tell me what I have done wrong.thanks!

Comment: If you are using Redux why do you try to set local state like that? Can't you get it from props via connect? So, you don't need to bother state again here. Your problem is trying to set a state which is not even there. Since your fetchUser is an async job, before it finishes you are trying to set your state from props.

Comment: @devserkan that setState was a try-out. I wasn't able to get the correct state from props via connect. With the fetch check I'm able to solve this problem. thanks for ur reply.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do the fetch in the componentWillMount or the componentDidMount lifecycle methods (with the caveat being that when you have a server rendered application you will get issues of syncing your server rendered html and your rehydrated html if you make the request in the componentWillMount.)

The reason why your this.state.userData is undefined is because the call for your data is asynchronous in nature. I recommend adding functionality to your component to check if the api call is being made (`isLoading` perhaps?), and if it is completed (`isLoaded` perhaps?).

In terms of implementation, it would go something like this, assuming you use the `connect` `react-redux` higher order component:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUser();
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, isLoaded, data } = this.props;
    if (isLoading) return <Loader />; // Or whatever you want to return when it is loading
    if (!isLoaded || !data) return null; // If it is not loading and its not loaded, then return nothing.
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{data.name}</h1>
        <h2>{data.id}</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isLoading: state.user.isLoading,
  isLoaded: state.user.isLoaded,
  userData: state.user.data
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchUser })(YourComponent);
```

In  your action dispatcher/middleware you will need to account for the start of the asynchronous call.
Assuming that is accounted for with something like redux thunk...

```
const initialState = {
  isLoaded: false,
  isLoading: false,
  data: {},
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      }
    case FETCH_USER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        isLoading: false,
        isLoaded: true,
        data: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

Comment: thanks for ur solution! it works now with the checks. Now I wonder, do I need use isLoading & isLoaded? at this moment I only check with isLoading(initial = true, after fetch = false).

Comment: There are at least three different states you should account for in my opinion- first, the initial state when no data is loaded and the call hasn’t quite started yet. Next, when the data is being fetched. And finally, when the fetching is done and the data is available. In your specific use case the first might seem redundant, but might be a good to have in case you change your logic a bit where the request is made after a certain set of conditions are met.

Comment: thanks for your solution, it can be used in most of other cases than only to the asked question.